# Web.Settings.User (User) and Web.Settings.User (HttpContext.User) in ASP.NET Core 6 C# are returning old values between the API calls

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-6.0

We are facing a weird issue after upgrade to .NET Core 6 from 3.1 in production environment.

In login API call, we are setting the user's claim principal with different parameters like `userId`, `currentClientId`, `parentClientId`, etc.

Initially, `currentClientId` and `parentClientId` are set to 0 in the login API. We have used `HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal...)` method to set the claims principal.

When user selects the client from the frontend, `setClient` API is called, where we are setting the `currentClientId` and `parentClientId` to any numeric value. We are refreshing the claims again by calling `HttpContext.SignInAsync(principal...)` with the updated principal (i.e. with updated value of `currentClientId` and `parentClientId`).

After the above API call an API to check if the user is logged in is called. This API gets the `contextUser` from `Web.Settings.User(HttpContext.User);`

We have used 2 ways to get the logged in User details:

1. Web.Settings.User(HttpContext.User)
2. Web.Settings.User(User)

For some reason, after updating to .NET Core 6, we have started getting contaminated values (i.e. previous values of `currentClientId` and `parentClientId`) Web.Settings.User(HttpContext.User) and Web.Settings.User(User), even though the new values were updated in the `setClient` API.

This issue is not occurring in the development environment at all but in production.

Comment: I suggest you could firstly make sure the your server codes has updated and then I suggest you could modify your codes to firstly signout the user and then sign in to update the claim/